# What "world" was Frodo in when Galadriel helped him?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-return-of-the-king, galadriel

As Frodo was attempting to flee Shelob's lair, he sort of collapses from fatigue. Then he is suddenly shown being in a plush forest during the golden hour when Galadriel "picks him up" by the hand, and he's immediately standing up outside the cave again. He's clearly not in the wraith spirit world as if he were wearing the One Ring.

[image]

Was Frodo temporarily beamed to somewhere in Lothlorien, near Galadriel? Did Galadriel go to him and change his surroundings while interacting? Does she have the ability to appear in dreams? Or was simply Frodo dreaming/imagining all of it?

How did Galadriel do this?

Comment: Man be tripping.

Comment: Looks to me like he's just hallucinating from hunger and fatigue. He's simply remembering the words of Galadriel in Lorien. No teleportation or anything, and this is not Galadriel's doing.

Comment: Is it really Galadriel, or is it really Elbereth (who Frodo had just called upon, at least in the book)?

Comment: It is strongly suggested to be Galadriel: it is the same actress and she wears an adamant ring. A portion of the ring is even seen on the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

### It's all a dream

> What you're seeing here is Peter Jackson adapting the films to make them more interesting than the books.
>
> This is a common occurrence in the films as Peter wanted to change the tone of certain scenes to build the tensions quicker than those in Tolkien's Lord of the Rings.
> <sub>– [Edlothiad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/68872/edlothiad)</sub>

This scene never happens in the books, so I **can't give you a canonical answer**. In the books, the chapter *Shelob's Lair* and *The Choices of Master Samwise* mostly happens in Sam's point of view.

The logical answer would be: it's all a hallucination.

Comment: Given Galadriel's penchant for teleportation and telepathy, perhaps this was a type of Hallucination Plus.

Comment: AYY! I got a reference! (but no link to the answer for the extra rep :( )

Comment: @iMerchant *Galadriel's penchant for teleportation?* What?

Comment: @Edlothiad - Didn't she teleport to/from the White Council in the Hobbit? At least in the movie, she vanished into thin air holding Gandalf's hand after the meeting.

Comment: "Hoom, hmm" - Treebeard. This would go under my above quote. But no. Canonically speaking, she can not Teleport. Not even the Valar can (according to some old writings). Tulkas had a string on two peaks between Valinor and ME so he could run across the sea quickly.

Answer (score -2):

## She breathes life and hope back to Frodo.

Let's first remember where Galadriel came from: born in Valinor, land of the Gods, while both trees Telperion (the silver tree) and Laurelin (the golden tree) were still untouched by Ungoliant (from which Shelob is a descendent). This was during the First Age, thousand of years before the Third Age and the war of the Ring.

By nature, almost all elves from that period were considered as blessed with great gifts and some measure of power, be it through craft, warfare, wisdom or intellect.

She also later received Nenya, one of the three Rings untouched by Sauron's evil, whose power was preservation, protection, and concealment from evil.
At this point, her powers were a match for Sauron himself. For instance, when the White Council finally agreed (well, Saruman especially) to take care of Dol Guldur, she was there to assist and lead the assault herself. She repels even the scrying eye of Sauron from Lothlórien and his armies never encroached deeply while she was in command.

Peter Jackson shows us how powerful she can be: even on the doorstep of Mordor, she can assist Frodo and give him the nudge he needs.

**There is no teleportation: only mental and psychological help from afar.**

Comment: Any comment on why my answer is not good enough would be welcome. Just because I'm not producing quotes or writing good engouh english should not be a reason for downvote.

Comment: One issue is that the only part of this answer that actually addresses the question is the very last line; everything else is just irrelevant backstory that fails to show why that line (rather than the other possibilities mentioned in the question) must be correct.

Comment: Moviewise she is a lot weaker than Sauron, as Galadriel herself said. OPs question isn't about the trees or the origins of Galadriel, what ring she wore or Ungoliant. And the orcs of Moria were assaulting Lothlórien while Galadriel was in charge(when the fellowship first reaches her but that is in the book not movie). That may be a reason why you have got a dislike,  but I don't know exactly, just answering your comment @Tjafaas

Comment: I simply don't think it's true. Frodo's just hallucinating.